# Не работают кнопки в telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, inline

Создаю бота телеграмм через [telebot](/questions/tagged/telebot), по неизвестной мне причине у меня не реагируют кнопки на нажатия, которые принимает `call`.
Пересмотрел весь код, но не могу найти ошибку

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bt1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Канал', url='https://t.me/+_zli2HIdIo4zYjc6')
    bt2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Каталог', callback_data='buy')
    bt3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Задать вопрос/Предложка', url='https://t.me/Rolexnalik')
    markup.row(bt1, bt2)
    markup.row(bt3)
    photo = open(r'C:\Users\metik\Desktop\broofsins_project\broofsins_photo.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption='Привет, друг!\n  \nНа связи команда Broofsins!\n  \nНаш девиз:Каждый день ты должен быть сильнее и лучше себя прошлого!\n \nМы хотим, чтобы ты развивался вместе с нами!\n \nПрисоединяйся!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def call_back(callback):
    if callback.data == 'buy':
        markup_1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        bt1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Lion's mane", callback_data='product1')
        bt2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('DMAE', callback_data='product2')
        bt3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('GABA', callback_data='product3')
        bt4 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Brain boost', callback_data='product4')
        bt5 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad')
        
        markup_1.row(bt1, bt2)
        markup_1.row(bt3, bt4)
        markup_1.row(bt5)
        
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        photo = open(r'C:\Users\metik\Desktop\broofsins_project\broofsins_photo.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(callback.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Выберите продукт:', reply_markup=markup_1)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def call_back(call):
    if call.data == 'nazad':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы вернулись в меню')
    else:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы не вернулись в меню')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: не совсем понял, а где тут упоминание `callback2`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не callback2, а call

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой - нужно перенести все `call` в `callback`, почему то библиотека [telebot](/questions/tagged/telebot) не может держать сразу две функции обратной связи.

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def call_back(callback):
    if callback.data == 'buy':
        markup_1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        bt1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Lion's mane", callback_data='product1')
        bt2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('DMAE', callback_data='product2')
        bt3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('GABA', callback_data='product3')
        bt4 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Brain boost', callback_data='product4')
        bt5 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='nazad')

        markup_1.row(bt1, bt2)
        markup_1.row(bt3, bt4)
        markup_1.row(bt5)

        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        photo = open(r'C:\Users\metik\Desktop\broofsins_project\broofsins_photo.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(callback.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Выберите продукт:', reply_markup=markup_1)
    elif callback.data == 'nazad':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Вы вернулись в меню')
    else:
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Вы не вернулись в меню')
```